# Cropped - sign on heavily downvoted answers

Tags: bug, design

It seems the - sign can get cropped on heavily downvoted answers.

For instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216359/break-statements-in-the-real-world?page=2&tab=votes#216406) (10K only), if we expand the score we see the -23 is composed from +78/-101, although it appears as +78/101;

[image]

It's a petty thing, but that is a good answer and think it deserves more (than -23 votes).

Comment: Can you add a screenshot here since not everybody can expand it (and also because the question is deleted)? Just the votes thing.

Comment: This is by design. The prefix is simply not shown for values lower than -99 (or higher than +99 for that matter).